# laravel set Mutator for input array

Tags: php, laravel, mutators

I have an array input in this format `name[{{$lang->code}}]` and it give me in run time

```
<input type="text" name="name[en]">
<input type="text" name="name[ar]">
```

then i tried to set Mutator for this field as below

```
public function setNameAttribute(array $json)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = $json;

}
```

and i got this message

> Array to string conversion

what should to do?

Note: at the end i am saving data in db in json format, it works but when try to save an Arabic language it change Arabic to slashes like that {"en":"sdf","ar":"//asd //asdasd asd/as/d/"} i am using casting object in my model.

Comment: What is  type of nam column e in DB ?

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to use cast instead of a mutator

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting